# Has iridescence ever been observed on any solar system body besides Earth? Or at least from a sample from one?

Tags: planetary-science, photography, imaging, measurement, optical

[New method for exoplanet detection based on iridescence?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/41208/7982) in Astronomy SE asks about observations of exoplanets, but here I'm asking about our own solar system bodies.

**Question:** Has iridescence ever been observed on any solar system body besides Earth? Or at least from a sample from one?

Primarily I'm interested in iridescence observed in a spacecraft's data, but observations on Earth from objects from off-Earth (e.g. sample returns, meteorites) are also okay.

---

Wikipedia's [Iridescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iridescence) begins:

> **Iridescence** (also known as **goniochromism**) is the phenomenon of certain surfaces that appear to gradually change color as the angle of view or the angle of illumination changes. Examples of iridescence include soap bubbles, feathers, butterfly wings and seashell nacre, as well as certain minerals. It is often created by [structural coloration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_coloration) (microstructures that interfere with light).

---

Companion question:

- [Has opalescence ever been observed on any solar system body besides Earth? Or at least from a sample from one?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54589/12102)

Comment: Does this count? https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/images/curiosity-spots-iridescent-mother-of-pearl-clouds

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff I looked up and added a definition of iridescence and surprisingly *it certainly does!*

Answer (score 4):

Iridescent "mother of pearl" clouds were observed by Curiosity on Mars: https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/images/curiosity-spots-iridescent-mother-of-pearl-clouds

---

From [PIA24662: Curiosity Spots Iridescent Mother of Pearl Clouds](https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA24662)

[image: NASA's Curiosity Mars rover spotted these iridescent, or "mother of pearl," clouds on March 5, 2021, the 3,048th Martian day, or sol, of the mission. Seen here are five images stitched together from a much wider panorama taken by the rover's Mast Camera, or Mastcam. The full panorama (Figure 1) was stitched together from 23 images.]

> NASA's Curiosity Mars rover spotted these iridescent, or "mother of pearl," clouds on March 5, 2021, the 3,048th Martian day, or sol, of the mission. Seen here are five images stitched together from a much wider panorama taken by the rover's Mast Camera, or Mastcam. The full panorama (Figure 1) was stitched together from 23 images.

The full 23 images stitched is linked on the page.